# For my movie watchlist application, is it okay to store the movie poster image on device?

Tags: ios, swift, image, caching, core-data

I'm working on a movie watchlist application for iOS. This is my first ever mobile app so I'm not really sure about the conventions.
The problem that I am facing is that each time the movie poster is displayed, an API is being used to fetch it online. This works fine and as intended when connected to the internet. Once there is no internet, it fails to fetch and shows nothing instead. No posters. Now, this is making me wonder if my whole approach is flawed. Do I just fetch and store the image in CoreData (iOS on-device database)?
I'm just worried what if a user saves a ton of movies, making the app take more space? Is this normal or am I missing a basic solution?

[image: App Screenshot]

Comment: It would depend how large the images are and if there is other metadata that goes along with it, like titles, summaries, ratings, etc. Is it an app that you would want to function offline? If so, consider storing information to the device, otherwise you could use placeholder images while the real ones load.

Comment: Are you using Kingfisher? Kingfisher has some cache options for image caching from url. Check this(https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) if you are not using it.

Comment: @BerkAkkerman Yup, I am using Kingfisher. Doesn't caching mean the posters will be gone once the app is closed? Because in that case it seems storing the poster in CoreData would make more sense, right?